# HERE.com : Generate the App Code for Javascript and REST

Tags: here-api

I  signed up to https://developer.here.com to geenrate the app ID and App code which irequire while configurating the resource under the Azure.  "App Code" is not available under the free account instead I am able to generate the App ID and App Key.

There is no proper documentation to get the App code as well.

[image]

I am trying to deploy below Workshop solution to Azure Environment and solution requires the API ID and API Code which I am not getting anywhere.

[enter link description here](https://developer.here.com/blog/real-time-fleet-tracking-workshop-for-azure-developers)

Comment: > "require while configurating the resource under the Azure"
Can you mention which Azure tutorial or documentation page are you following, that mentions app id and app code requirement?

Answer (score 1):

there is no support for app id and app code anymore and furthermore, no "second rest section"

Comment: How to make this repository work with API Key :https://github.com/heremaps/devrel-workshops/tree/master/azure/fleetmanagement

Answer (score -1):

**APP ID** and **APP CODE** have been deprecated and you should use **Apikey** or **OAuth 2.0** (JSON web token) instead.

If you really need to use **APP ID** and **APP CODE**, they can be generated within second "REST" section:

[image]